# Mac Grapher - import point sets from many files quickly

Tags: macos

I have like 100 files, each containing a point set. Is there a way to import them all quickly into Grapher as separate point sets?

Grapher isn't scriptable as far as I know and I can't find an option in the menu to import a batch of point sets.

For now I wrote a program that merges all the point set files together so I can load them as one big point set, but that is just a temporary solution that has some disadvantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so currently this is just not possible.